# How to set Author for SVN

Tags: svn, author, smartsvn

How can i set the author in svn? i use smart svn?

Comment: The author of a file says i commit file.txt the file should have flags  like author:myname or so

Comment: not my correct name another how can i set my own?

Comment: so you're looking to set an author to a file when it's first committed?

Comment: I know that this question is old, but I don't understand if "i use smart svn?" is a question, or a statement. Please clarify thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to see author in file properties. Is it right?
I don't know how to do it in smart svn while I use command line or TortoiseSVN.

In Windows with TortoiseSVN use file context menu and click on file properties. There is "Subversion" tab. In this tab you can add properties. To add author you should add"

```
property name=svn:keywords
property value=Author Date Id Revision
```

If you want to add such property to all files you add to repository then look at your Subversion config file: `c:\Documents and Settings\[user]\[AppData]\Subversion\config`

there is `auto-props` section and set it to:

```
[auto-props]
* = svn:keywords=Author Date Id Revision
```

(this works only for new files that you add to repository).

There is [documentation of svn file properties](http://mikewest.org/2006/06/working-with-subversion-file-properties)

Answer (score 1):

The author of a given commit is stored in SVN as a revision property, namely svn:author. This will automatically be set to the user specified in the svn commit command (or the username specified when prompted for credentials if no user is specified in the command and anonymous commits are disallowed)

After a commit occurs, it can be possible to edit the specific properties, depending on the server configuration. This is very similar to editing a revision's log message, as specified in the response to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-to-edit-log-message-already-committed-in-subversion)

However in this case, assuming revision property edits are enabled for your repostory on the server, you will want to edit the svn:author property as follows:

svn ps svn:author "author_name" --revprop -r revision_number "repository_url"