# Editing the Subversion Logs

Tags: svn, logging

A developer of ours tends not to specify messages when committing his code, I know I could jump up and down and force him to do so from here on in, but how do I deal with the previous commits.

I'd very much like to go in and edit the messages so that they are descriptive of what they do.

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-commit-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion

Comment: Agreed. Answers here are slightly different.Specifically relate to do it in a bulk way. (The Tortoise SVN answer specifically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a specific client for subversion, or just the command line?  With TortoiseSVN when you have the list of log messages open, you can right-click on one and choose "Edit log message".

This link describes how to do it if you don't have TortoiseSVN (doesn't sound easy):
http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2008/01/24/subversion-changing-log-messages.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Play around with this

```
$ svn propset --revprop -r 25 svn:log "Journaled about trip to New York."
property 'svn:log' set on repository revision '25'
```

From the Subverion site: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html

Answer (score 0):

Does [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-commit-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion) answer you enough?  Your question seems slightly different in one nuance:  that question is more for 1 commit, this is for a large chunk of commits presumably.  So, for the amount of work it may take this may not be good enough, but if it's not a huge number of changes maybe this is okay.