# How do I create a folder name with a yyyymmddhhmmss-prefix?

Tags: windows, datetime, directory, naming-conventions, mkdir

I'm using code (from [Windows batch: formatted date into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945572/windows-batch-formatted-date-into-variable) ).

1. How to get Mon=08 (2-digits), instead of Aug (3-alpha)?
2. What is syntax for MKDIR using a variable? With leading \ I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."  Without I get "access is denied."

   ```
    @echo off
    setlocal 
    for /f "skip=8 tokens=2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=: " %%D in ('robocopy /l * \ \  /ns /nc /ndl /nfl /np /njh /XF * /XD *') do (
    set "dow=%%D"
    set "month=%%E"
    set "day=%%F"
    set "HH=%%G"
    set "MM=%%H"
    set "SS=%%I"
    set "year=%%J"
    SET "DESTINATION=%%J%%E%%F%%G%%H%%I-EXTRACTION"
   )

    echo Day of the week: %dow%
    echo Day of the month : %day%
    echo Month : %month%
    echo hour : %HH%
    echo minutes : %MM%
    echo seconds : %SS%
    echo year : %year%
    echo DESTINATION : %DESTINATION%

    endlocal

    MKDIR \%DESTINATION%\
   ```

Comment: See the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472631/how-do-i-get-the-day-month-and-year-from-a-windows-cmd-exe-script

Answer (score 0):

1. This would be an easy way to do it.

`set "folder_name=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%-EXTRACTION"
md "%folder_name%"`

2. In the above program you just need to put  MKDIR "%DESTINATION%" before endlocal and the %DESTINATION% should be inside double quote.

`MKDIR "%DESTINATION%" 
endlocal`