# What does %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% mean?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this part of script that create a variable called `fileName` used later to name a file.

```
set fileName=db_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.bak
```

What does `%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%` mean?

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString

Comment: it's a terrible way to get date. Use a locale-independent method instead: [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/995714) https://stackoverflow.com/q/5594121/995714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3472631/995714

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Opening a command prompt window and running there `set /?` outputs the help for command **SET**.

There is explained on last help page that `%DATE%` expands to the **current locale date** and `%TIME%` to the **current locale time** on parsing the line containing those **dynamic** variable references.

The format of the date and the time depends on Windows region and language settings. It is necessary for that reason to execute in a command prompt window:

```
echo Date is: %DATE%
echo Time is: %TIME%
```

or alternatively

```
echo %DATE% %TIME%
```

best executed before 10:00 AM to know the locale date and time string formats. Is the date with weekday? What is the order of day, month, and year in date string? Is the time in 12- or 24-hours format? Is the time always with a two-digit hour?

In output help of command **SET** is explained also `%Variable:~X,Y%` to get a substring of a string of a variable value from position `X` in string with `Y` characters length.

The first character in a string has position number (character index) `0`.
A negative value for `X` means `X` characters from end of string (from right side).

```
set fileName=db_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.bak
```

The above command line defines an environment variable with name `fileName`

- starting with fixed string `db_`,
- appending with `%date:~-4,4%` the last four characters of the current locale date which is obviously the year,
- appending with `%date:~-10,2%` the tenth and ninth characters from right side of the current locale date which is most likely the month,
- appending with `%date:~-7,2%` the seventh and sixth characters from right side of the current locale date which is most likely the day,
- appending an underscore as separator between date in format `yyyyMMdd` and time in format `HHmm`,
- appending with `%time:~0,2%` the first two characters of the current locale time which is obviously the hour with always two digits in 24-hour format,
- appending with `%time:~3,2%` the fourth and fifth character of the current locale time which is obviously the minute and
- appending the file extension `.bak`.

The result of this variable definition with several substrings can be verified by executing in a command prompt window:

```
echo db_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.bak
```

The substring references from date string are done from right side (end of string) instead of left side (beginning of string) to make the definition independent on weekday present or missing at the beginning of the date string.

Answer (score 0):

Using SET in DOS sets an environment variable that can be later retrieved by other DOS Commands, either directly or via Batch Files.

For example;

**SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\MyStuff**

The above adds C:\MyStuff to the Path.

**SET FRIEDRICE=YES**

This creates an environment variable called FRIEDRICE and sets the value to YES.

The value set is only valid for the current command prompt session unless it's set more permanently using other methods.

In the good old days AUTOEXEC.BAT was often used to set up the basic operating environment.

**EDIT**

*Mofi is quite right in his answer. The right side of the SET command, in your case, is setting a Filename (for later use somewhere) into the current environment variables. Sadly I misunderstood the question and thought you were asking about SET rather than what was being set.
You can test your SET commands by typing SET (with no paremeters) in your command prompt. The current environment variables will be echoed.*