# WHEN MAKE .bat file and run do not work WINDOWS 7

Tags: cmd

```
D:\> set "today=%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%"

D:\> mkdir SVN_BACKUP_DUMP_TEST\%today%

D:\> CD SVN_BACKUP_DUMP_TEST\%today%
```

when we are make bat file this command not work

Answer (score 0):

Format of date of referenced environment variable `DATE` depends on region setting, i.e. which country and derived from country which date format is configured for the current account. So which string is assigned to environment variable `today` and if that string is valid for a directory or file name depends on account specific date format.

On my computer with German set as country for my account output of `echo %DATE%` is `13.11.2017`. So the date format is `dd.MM.yyyy` with point as separator, no weekday and always two digits for date and month even for a date or month less than 10.

The command line

```
echo %DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%
```

produces on my machine with my account and my region settings the output:

```
-01-1.
```

That is definitely not the current date in format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

The solution is using following batch code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "Today=%%I"
set "Today=%Today:~0,4%-%Today:~4,2%-%Today:~6,2%"
mkdir "SVN_BACKUP_DUMP_TEST\%Today%" 2>nul
cd "SVN_BACKUP_DUMP_TEST\%Today%"
```

This is a region independent solution. The batch code is completely explained in answer on
[Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322/3074564)

[What does %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37236739/3074564) is one more question on which answer should be read to understand the string substitutions. And run in a command prompt window `set /?` to get displayed the help for command **SET** explaining string substitution, too.

Comment: Specifying the full path to `wmic.exe` is a nice defensive move.