# How to overwrite existing .rar archive on adding files and folders to an archive?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, winrar

I'm using WinRAR command line for archiving files into a predefined location with the name of the date like: `20171206.rar` 
When I rerun the command, I want the RAR file to be replaced and not updated. I went through the list of WinRAR command line switches but found nothing that gets me the desired result.

Any and all comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

*WinRAR* has no command or switch to ignore an existing archive file on compressing files and folders into an archive like all compression tools I'm aware of.

*WinRAR* has the command **d** to delete files in an archive with deleting the archive file itself on finally not containing any file. But I think it is not advisable to use *WinRAR* with command **d** to just delete an archive file before creating a new archive file with same name.

I use for archiving source files the switch `-agYYYY-MM-DD_NN` making it possible for me to create more than one individual archive per day for backup purposes. *WinRAR* automatically creates RAR archive files with current date in format `yyyy-MM-dd` in file name with an incremented number because of `NN`, i.e. `2017-12-06_01.rar`, `2017-12-06_02.rar`, ...,  `2017-12-07_01.rar`, and so on. I delete manually the backup archives no longer needed from time to time.

I suggest the following batch file for your task:

```
@echo off
if not exist "20??????.rar" goto CreateDayArchive
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "FileNameDate=%%I"
del "%FileNameDate:~0,8%.rar" 2>nul
set "FileNameDate="

:CreateDayArchive
rem The RAR/WinRAR command line to create the new archive with current date.
```

The **FOR** command line to get current date in format `yyyyMMdd` region independent is explained in detail for example at [Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322/3074564)

The usage of the environment variable `DATE` would be much faster than using the command **WMIC**. But the date format of the environment variable `DATE` depends on Windows region and language settings. On my computer the date value of the environment variable `DATE` is always in format `dd.MM.yyyy` which makes it possible to use this much faster batch file:

```
@echo off
del "%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%.rar" 2>nul
rem The RAR/WinRAR command line to create the new archive with current date.
```

This code works also with `/` or `-` as separator instead of `.` as well as for date strings with abbreviated weekday at beginning because year, month and day are substituted from `DATE` string from right side. So a date like `Wed, 06/12/2017` (6<sup>th</sup> December 2017) would be also processed correct by this fast batch code variant.

If the region dependent date format of `DATE` is `MM/dd/yyyy` without or with abbreviated weekday at beginning, the following batch file could be used with day and month substitution exchanged.

```
@echo off
del "%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-10,2%%DATE:~-7,2%.rar" 2>nul
rem The RAR/WinRAR command line to create the new archive with current date.
```

See also answer on [What does %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37236739/3074564) for a complete explanation on date string substitution to reformat region dependent `DATE` value into the wanted date format.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` used here to suppress the error message output by **DEL** to handle **STDERR** by redirecting it to device **NUL** if there is no RAR archive file with current date in file name in the current directory.