# How can multiple dependent variables be set on the same line in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

This was inspired by [another post on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/324287/53249), on how to backup some files using a batch script.

The following block creates a variable with the current date/time string:

```
REM -- Get the current date/time stamp
set DS=%date%
set TS=%time: =0%
set mm=%DS:~4,2%
set dd=%DS:~7,2%
set yyyy=%DS:~10,4%
set hh=%TS:~0,2%
set min=%TS:~3,2%
set ss=%TS:~6,2%
set ms=%TS:~9,2%
set DT_STAMP=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%_%hh%.%min%.%ss%
```

As a script writer, it is often convenient to consolidate these down to a single line. However, in this case, condensing this to a single line is extremely difficult, if not impossible.

There does not seem to be a way to put multiple `set` commands on a single line. Separating commands with `&` or `&&` works fine, but commands on the right cannot be dependent on variables that were set earlier on the same line.

Also, notice how the `time` variable **must** have `spaces` replaced with zeros `0`. There does not seem to be a way to do both a string replacement **and** get a sub-string on the same line.

Is there any way to get this down to one line? The closest I can get is two lines:

```
set DS=%date% && set TS=%time: =0%
set DT_STAMP=%DS:~10,4%-%DS:~4,2%-%DS:~7,2%_%TS:~0,2%.%TS:~3,2%.%TS:~6,2%
```

---

#### Update

This has gathered some good answers; allow me to clarify what an accepted answer must have:

- **An ugly, but re-usable, single line solution is OK** *(the pretty version is already provided above)*
- **Standard shell commands only** *(PowerShell and similar must be avoided; if I wanted those, I'd just do the whole thing in PowerShell)*
- Ability to format the date in any logical format *(should be able to do anything the pretty version above can do, not just support ISO formatted dates using shorthand notation)*
- It is OK to ignore localization settings *(really, just this one time!)*
- **Must be on a single line!** *(for instance, [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is handy, but can have nasty side-effects, is not re-usable in every context, and usually requires multiple lines)*

Comment: writing this in one line doesn't make it more readable

Comment: The first large block of code is the readable one. The challenge I am trying to solve is getting the whole thing on a reusable, single line (with no side effects).

Comment: A one-line solution might look like a desirable thing for programmers, but if it isn't readable any more it doesn't help in the long run. I'd prefer a readable subroutine with `call :GetFormattedDate` or an "external" solution with `call GetFormattedDate.bat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done as requested using the dynamic environment variables `DATE` and `TIME` with date and time being [region/country dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) using the command line:

```
@set "DT_STAMP=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%" & call set "DT_STAMP=%%DT_STAMP: =0%%"
```

It is expected by this command line that `DATE` has a date string like `Sat 09/15/2018` and `TIME` has a time string like  `4:18:23,56` and is in 24 hours format.

The environment variable `DT_STAMP` has value `2018-09-15_04.18.23` for the given example date and time strings.

Better would be using the command line:

```
@set "DT_STAMP=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~-10,2%-%DATE:~-7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%" & call set "DT_STAMP=%%DT_STAMP: =0%%"
```

This second version has the advantage that it does not matter if date string starts with weekday or not. But date string must have the format `MM/dd/yyyy` (MDY) with any type of separator like `/` or `.` or `-`.

But most countries use `dd.MM.yyyy` (DMY) (with different separator) which would require a small modification:

```
@set "DT_STAMP=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~-7,2%-%DATE:~-10,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%" & call set "DT_STAMP=%%DT_STAMP: =0%%"
```

See also [What does %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37236739/3074564)

The replacement of all spaces by `0` is done on same command line by using a second **SET** command which references the environment variable `DT_STAMP` with `%%` on both sides instead of just `%`.

The two `%%` are replaced by `cmd.exe` during parsing the command line to `%` before executing the first **SET** command. So the command line finally executed is for example:

```
@set "DT_STAMP=2018-09-15_ 4.18.23" & call set "DT_STAMP=%DT_STAMP: =0%"
```

The usage of **CALL** results in a second parsing of the command line part after operator `&` by `cmd.exe`. Therefore the second **SET** has as argument `"DT_STAMP=2018-09-15_04.18.23"` and the environment variable `DT_STAMP` gets assigned finally the wanted date/time string.

But better would be getting the current local date/time string in wanted format independent on region/country setting which is possible also with a single command line:

```
@for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do @set "DT_STAMP=%%I" & call set "DT_STAMP=%%DT_STAMP:~0,4%%-%%DT_STAMP:~4,2%%-%%DT_STAMP:~6,2%%_%%DT_STAMP:~8,2%%.%%DT_STAMP:~10,2%%.%%DT_STAMP:~12,2%%"
```

It uses **WMIC** to get current local date/time region independent and once again **CALL** and **SET** to reformat the date/time string never containing a space to wanted format.

See my answer on [Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322/3074564) for an explanation on how **WMIC** output is processed by this command line.

By the way: `.` is used usually as separator between file name and file extension. For that reason it would be better to use also `-` instead of `.` between hour and minute and between minute and second.

One more note: The command after `call` can be also any other command which uses the date/time string directly for example in a file/folder name/path.

Comment: This is the most clear and complete answer to the original question. The other answers have all been very helpful, but it is the `call set` that was new to me, and is the insight that I was hoping for. And you even included ways to do this independent of region/country: so great!

Answer (score 3):

It's trivial with a FOR /F statement, but as npocmaka already said, it depends on localization.

I assume your date/time looks like

```
Fri 09/14/2018
 8:15:46.12
```

Then this works

```
for /F "tokens=1-7 delims=/:,. " %%1 in ("%date% %time: =0%") do set DT_STAMP=%%4-%%2-%%3_%%5.%%6.%%7
```

But for german localization you need

```
for /F "tokens=1-7 delims=/:,. " %%1 in ("%date% %time: =0%") do set DT_STAMP=%%3-%%2-%%1_%%4h%%5m%%6s
```

**Solution with a batch macro**

You could build a batch macro, the use of macros is more readable, but the macros itself are a bit more complicated

Using the macro, it assigns the current timestamp to the variable myDT1:

```
%@AssignTimeStamp% myDT1
echo %myDT1%
```

The definition of the macro (delayed expansion has to be disabled while defining the macro):

```
REM *** Macro definition, be sure that there aren't any trailing whitespaces
set ^"LF=^
%= This creates a variable containing a single linefeed (0x0A) character =%
^"
:: Define %\M% to effectively issue a newline with line continuation
set ^"\M=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"

set @AssignTimeStamp=for %%. in (1 2) do if %%.==2 (%\M%
    %= The next line builds the timestamp =%%\M%
    for /F "tokens=1-7 delims=/:,. " %%1 in ("%date% %time: =0%") do set timestamp=%%4-%%2-%%3_%%5h%%6m%%7s%\M%
    %= When a variable name was give then store the timestamp there, else output the timestamp =%%\M%
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%1 in ("#,!argv!") do ( %\M%
        for %%V in (!timestamp!) do endlocal^&if "%%~2" neq "" (set "%%2=%%V") else echo ##%%V%\M%
    )%\M%
) else setlocal enableDelayedExpansion^&set argv=,
```

Comment: This is why offering a bounty was worthwhile. The simple things you don't think of! Continuing my own research revealed similar answers from [Matthew Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3859042/2657515) and [John Langstaff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16264795/2657515). (Thank you jeb for writing this up, and thank you, The Sidebar, for pointing out the related question.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can - with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion&set "DS=%date%"&& set "TS=%time: =0%"&set "DT_STAMP=!DS:~10,4!-!DS:~4,2!-!DS:~7,2!_!TS:~0,2!.!TS:~3,2!.!TS:~6,2!"
```

But this a bad way to format the date time as it depends on localization settings.Why you want to do this on one line? For settings independent approach check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-datetime-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format/19799236#19799236).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want an ISO-8601-like formatted date. This will produce a correctly formatted date regardless of the regional/culture settings of the system. If this is used inside a .bat script file, double the `%` characters on the `d` variable.

```
FOR /F %d IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command Get-Date -UFormat %Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S') DO (SET "DT_STAMP=%d")
```

Or, directly in PowerShell:

```
$DT_STAMP = Get-Date -UFormat %Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S
```