# Rename files with current date stamp (bat files)

Tags: batch-file

I have bat file to run sql procedure which is creating 2 files:

**TEST_SCHEMA.dmp**

**TEST_SCHEMA.log**

Then I used xcopy to copy files. After copy I want to change the file name to:

TEST_SCHEMA.dmp -> TEST_CURRENT_DATE.dmp

TEST_SCHEMA.log -> TEST_CURRENT_DATE.log

*where* **Current_Date = YYYYMMDDHHMM**

This is what I had so far:

```
set OWNER=myOwner
set FILE_NAME=TEST_SCHEMA
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1

sqlplus %OWNER%/%OWNER%@host:1521/SID @run_test.sql %OWNER% %FILE_NAME%
xcopy "\\host\c$\abc\def\test\%FILE_NAME%.*" /C

set "_year=%MyDate:~0,4%"
set "_month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "_day=%MyDate:~6,2%"

ren FILE_NAME.dmp "TEST (%_year%%_month%%_day%).txt"
ren FILE_NAME.log "TEST (%_year%%_month%%_day%).txt"

pause 0
```

Result should be like:

TEST_201806131006.dmp

TEST_201806131006.log

But I don't know how to correctly use rename and put date to file name.

Comment: Can you include the date in the filename within SQL\*Plus?

Comment: no, I need to do it into bat, also uder FILE_NAME I can put directly names with date, but how to display correct dates?

Comment: So it's not an Oracle question at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using WMIC to create the DateTime stamp:

```bat
For /F %%A In ('WMIC OS Get LocalDateTime') Do If Not "%%~xA"=="" Set "ds=%%~nA"
Ren "TEST_*.*" "TEST_%ds:~,-2%.*"
```

Comment: Should there not be `"delims=."` to remove fractional seconds and time zone?

Comment: @aschipfl, no, because that is removed extension like _by retaining only the name portion using `%~n`_.

Comment: Ah, very clever, I didn't spot that!

Answer (score 1):

Create the file including the date stamp.

```
set OWNER=myOwner
for /f %%A in ('
  powershell -nop -c "get-date -f yyyyMMdd"
') do SET "FILE_NAME=TEST_SCHEMA_%%A"
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1

sqlplus %OWNER%/%OWNER%@host:1521/SID @run_test.sql %OWNER% %FILE_NAME%
xcopy "\\host\c$\abc\def\test\%FILE_NAME%.*" /C
```

Comment: I got message as: sqlplus is not recognized as an internal or extarnal command, operable program or batch file

Comment: My inserted command just sets an environment variable, it doesn't change dir or path. Looks like you are doing something differently than in your batch.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers seem a little complicated to me.  I  have some files that I am constantly updating as I develop a program.  In case I break something and don't realize immediatly I needed a way to backup several times a day.  This is what I put in my batch program (modified for your file name) which I then control via Windows Task Scheduler. (I actually xcopy the folder I'm working on and then rename it with the date/time adjustment.)

```
ren TEST_SCHEMA.dmp "TEST_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.dmp"
```

My thanks to Mofi for providing his answer to another user here...

[What does %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147552/what-does-date-4-4date-10-2date-7-2-time0-2time3-2-mean)