# Windows batch command to create backup folder and replace folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I need to backup an existing folder with date-time stamp and replace it (delete and recreate) with new content inside the folder.

Does anyone have a script to do this?

I tried the following code, where `%ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath% = \\servername\foldername`

```
IF EXIST %ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release (

REM Get current date time
@echo off
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c_%%b_%%a)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
set backup_folder=%mydate%_%mytime%
MD %ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\%backup_folder%

REM Copy current folder to backup folder
Copy %ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release %ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\%backup_folder% 

REM Delete Existing Release folder 
RD %ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release /S /Q
)

MD %ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **command** `date` with parameter `/T` outputs the current date in format defined by configured country for current user account. Exactly the same date string can be accessed by referencing dynamic **environment variable** `DATE` for example with `%DATE%`.

The **command** `time` with parameter `/T` outputs the current time in format defined by configured country for current user account. Exactly the same time string can be accessed by referencing dynamic **environment variable** `TIME` for example with `%TIME%`.

What happens on execution of this command line?

```
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c_%%b_%%a)
```

`for` respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file starts in background one more command process using `%ComSpec% /c` with the command line between `'`. So executed in background is following with Windows installed in `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c date /t
```

The output of **command** `date` to handle **STDOUT** of this command process in background is captured by **FOR** respectively Windows command processor instance executing the batch file.

The captured line is split up into three substrings using `/` as string delimiter assigned to the loop variables `a`, `b` and `c` which are concatenated together in reverse order with underscore as delimiter.

This task can be done much faster by replacing `'date /t'` by `"%DATE%"`. In this case **FOR** processes the date **string** expanded by already running `cmd.exe` on parsing this command line before executing **FOR**. So there is no starting of one more `cmd.exe` in background and capturing its output just to process the same date **string** which makes batch file execution a bit faster.

The same is true for `'time /t'` which can be replaced by `"%TIME%"`.

But the two **FOR** loops could be completely optimized away by using string substitution as described for example by answer on [What does %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37236739/3074564) and region dependent date and time format is well known for example by running in a command prompt window:

```
echo %DATE% %TIME%
```

This command outputs on my computer with German date/time format according to configured country:

```
24.07.2019 20:15:29,90
```

It can be seen on this output that the original code would not work on my Windows computer with my account because of date string contains `.` and not `/` and time string contains a comma.

So better would be using a region independent solution as explained very detailed in answer on [Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322/3074564) The disadvantage is that execution of `wmic.exe` takes much longer than `cmd.exe` needs to reformat date and time string to `yyyy_MM_dd_HHmm`. However, the batch file is executed most likely not very often per day, and so it does not really matter if execution to get date/time in this format takes some milliseconds or about one second.

Copying the entire folder is not really necessary in this case. It should be enough to rename it with:

```
ren "%ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\release" "%backup_folder%"
```

The command `move` could be also used if command `ren` cannot be used for unknown reasons.

However, the main problem is missing knowledge about how and when to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `set /?` and read the output help explaining on an **IF** and a **FOR** example delayed environment variable expansion.

The issue here is that `backup_folder` is not defined on executing the command lines referencing it with `%backup_folder%` because of all occurrences of `%variable%` are replaced by Windows command processor already on parsing entire command block starting here with `(` on **IF** condition at top by current value of the referenced environment variable before executing the command **IF**.

So executed on existing release folder is:

```
set backup_folder=
MD \\servername\foldername\

REM Copy current folder to backup folder
Copy \\servername\foldername\Release \\servername\foldername\ 

REM Delete Existing Release folder 
RD \\servername\foldername\Release /S /Q
```

This can be seen by [debugging the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

The solution is here avoiding the command block by changing the first **IF** condition.

Fast region **dependent** solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath=\\servername\foldername"

if not exist "%ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release\" goto CreateFolder

ren "%ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release" "%DATE:~-4%_%DATE:~-7,2%_%DATE:~-10,2%_%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%"

:CreateFolder
md "%ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release"
endlocal
```

Slower region **independent** solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath=\\servername\foldername"

if not exist "%ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release\" goto CreateFolder

for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "BackupDateTime=%%I"
set "BackupDateTime=%BackupDateTime:~0,4%_%BackupDateTime:~4,2%_%BackupDateTime:~6,2%_%BackupDateTime:~8,4%"
ren "%ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release" "%BackupDateTime%"

:CreateFolder
md "%ApplicationDeploymentFolderPath%\Release"
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`