# How to echo command result in the command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, echo, command-prompt

I want to echo the result of dir comamnd in the command prompt.
How do I do that?
I've already tried:

1. echo dir
2. echo $dir

Comment: Run `dir` instead of `echo dir`. Please run in the command prompt window the command `help` to get output an incomplete list of [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) with a brief description. Every Windows command can be executed with `/?` as argument to get output its usage help in the command prompt window. Try that out with `echo /?` and with `dir /?`.

Answer (score 1):

an example of this shown in another stackoverflow post is.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('date /t') DO set today=%i
echo %today%
```

Displays todays current day.
u could replace that for dir.

Comment: Why is used one of the worst examples from all of the thousands of examples which demonstrate how to capture the output of a command line, process the captured output with `for /F`, and define an environment variable with a string value of (part of) captured output? I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57189369/3074564) why the first command line in your answer is one of the worst methods to get current date. The first line can be removed and second line changed to `echo %DATE%` to get same output much faster.