# Windows batch: Validating a date with regex using findstr /r

Tags: regex, windows, date, batch-file, findstr

I'm stuck on understanding why a similar regular expression is failing in a Windows batch file, or on the command line.

This regular expression works fine:

```bash
echo %Date%|findstr /r "^[mtwtfsMTWTFS][ouehra][nedurt] (3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])(\/|-)(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])\2([0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$"
```

As expected, it returns:

```
Mon 03/11/2024
```

This code fails:

```bash
set passed_date=03/11/2024
echo %passed_date%|findstr /r "^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])(\/|-)(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])\2([0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$"
```

It doesn't return anything, so I'm unclear as to why the second regular expression is failing.

I rewrote the regex:

```bash
echo %passed_date%|findstr /r "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\/)(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/)(2[0-9][0-9]{2})$"
```

But it still doesn't return anything.

I also placed the regex into [REGEX 101](https://regex101.com/), where it extracts what I was looking for.

I'm not interested in using any alternative methods of validating the date, I'm just trying to understand why one works and one doesn't.

Comment: `findstr` uses BRE, which, horrifically, never appears on any regex verification website that I'm able to find. The fact of the matter is that if you want to use regex with `findstr`, you're limited exclusively to character classes. No quantifiers and no groups.

Comment: That's why I'm stuck, because the first regex works fine using groups and alternations.

Comment: Your working regex is matching on its first pattern `"^[mtwtfsMTWTFS][ouehra][nedurt]` only. The space you have used separates patterns to match, so your second pattern ```(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])(\/|-)(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])\2([0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$"```, which is not valid for findstr, does not matter. You can test this against any strings which begin with `mon`, `Mon`, `tue`, `Tue`, `wed`, `Wed`, `thu`, `Fri`, `fri`, `Sat`, `sat`, `Sun`, or `sun`. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, the limited regex is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I just stumbled upon that "space" issue. That makes sense now. I was reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr and trying to get something to work. I guess I'll go a different direction now.

Comment: BTW, I should mention that the environment variable named `DATE` only begins with an abbreviated three letter English day name in a limited number of Windows Operating Systems, so not even your first pattern would match on most PC's.

Comment: Understood. This is part of a complete matching routine. That is just one part. I've just gone to these two for now:

echo %Date%|findstr /r "^[mtwtfsMTWTFS][ouehra][nedurt] [0-1][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" and echo %passed_date%| findstr /r "^[0-1][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" which will get me what I need in the short term.

Comment: @Elk checking`%date%` is an extremely bad way because it's locale dependent and can be changed easily in seconds with a simple settings change. Use a locale-independent way to get data instead: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56165593/995714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3472631/995714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/995714 and nowadays you should use powershell, it's much easier to obtain things and do validation there

Comment: As long as you're happy to accept that `%passed_date%` is valid with a value string `10/00/1000`, or `19/99/1999`, who are we to argue @Elk.