# Automatically add revision number to SVN in the comments on commit?

Tags: svn, jira

we're using JIRA with svn and looking for a way to include the revision id of the file automatically in the comment that appears in the dialog when commiting the file(s) so that JIRA catch that task.

Something like [ E-2 ] where the '2' is the id of the revision set by svn. Is there a way to create somethin similar to [ E- $id$ ] or something like that?

Thanks.

Edit : Well i've solved a part of it reading this [enter link description here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+Subversion), i hope someone helps this.

Comment: Perhaps one of the [svn hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html) (such as pre-commit) could be used? Although that would always be lagging, I imagine...

Comment: i'm looking at that... but i was thinking in an easier way to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that revision number are not different for each file, each revision number identifies a snapshot for the whole repository. See [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs) for details

Comment: there must be an easier way... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the JIRA/Subversion integrations I've used (svn plugin, fisheye) handle this automatically. You add the JIRA issue key such as "TEST-123" somewhere in the svn commit message, and then the integration periodically notes all new commits and looks for JIRA issue keys in their messages. Then each JIRA issue has a tab with the list of commits associated with that issue. So there's no need to embed svn revision numbers into commit messages.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But the problem is when you forgot or someone of your team forgot to set the id when he/she commit... then jira looses that task and when you want to export a certain task you'll not find it until you look carefully. I'm looking to automatically insert it int the comment of the commit to prevent this issue.

Comment: You can also change the commit message after the fact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion

Comment: yep, but i'm looking to set it before, maybe a template?

Comment: If you use Eclipse with Mylyn and JIRA connector, this would be a toolset where the template is what you like to have. Where should Subversion get the information when you commit on which JIRA issue you were working?

Comment: i use Mylyn but the template of Mylyn does not handle the svn revision number to set it with the template message when commit. Sometime ago i asked if mylyn support this kind of feature but did not. The info that svn must handle is the revision number that appears at the right of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not in the habit of doing commits in a particular way, and you don't mind doing a bit of scripting, this is what comes to mind -- I will probably do something like this myself, though I am using HG and not SVN...

Get the command line interface for Jira, rig it up so you can download 'my issues' into a list, parse the list with a script to create separate *.issue files that get dumped in a directory. Then as you work on issues, you move them from that directory, to a 'done' directory. When you are ready to commit, you run another script that creates a template for your commit message which includes all the done issues -- then you fill in the blanks for each issue.

You don't even need the CLI really, if all your *.issue files are associated with a script that will delete the file and add its ID to a commit template, then you can just create your own ID.issues files by hand. (empty files)

All that would be left is to script the commit.