# sharpsvn logmessage edit sharpsvn?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

use the sharpsvn.
The specific revision logmessage want to change.

It is implemented like '[show log] -[edit logmessage]' of svn.

I am awkward in English.
so, to help you understand.
my code is attached.

```
        public void logEdit()
    { 
        Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logitems = new Collection<SvnLogEventArgs>();

        SvnRevisionRange range = new SvnRevisionRange(277, 277);
        SvnLogArgs arg = new SvnLogArgs( range ) ;

        m_svn.GetLog(new System.Uri(m_targetPath), arg, out logitems);

        SvnLogEventArgs logs;
        foreach (var logentry in logitems)
        {
            string autor = logentry.LogMessage; // only read ..
            // autor += "AA";
        }

       // m_svn.Log( new System.Uri(m_targetPath), new System.EventHandler<SvnLogEventArgs> ());

    }
```

Comment: not clear what you are trying to ask?

Comment: sharpsvn을 이용해 c#에서 svn의 '[edit logmessage]' 처럼 작동하게 만들고 싶습니다.
from c # using sharpsvn, like '[edit logmessage]' svn would like to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Every log message in Subversion is stored as a revision property, ie metadata that goes with each revision. See the [complete list of subversion properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.properties.html). Also have a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304390/5555) and the Subversion [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg). The related answer shows that what you want to do is something like:

```
svn propedit -r 277 --revprop svn:log "new log message" <path or url>
```

On a standard repository this causes an error because the default behavior is that revision properties cannot be modified. See the [FAQ entry](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg) about changing log messages on how to change that with a `pre-revprop-change` repository hook.

Translated to SharpSvn:

```
public void ChangeLogMessage(Uri repositoryRoot, long revision, string newMessage)
{
    using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
    {
        SvnSetRevisionPropertyArgs sa = new SvnSetRevisionPropertyArgs();

        // Here we prevent an exception from being thrown when the 
        // repository doesn't have support for changing log messages
        sa.AddExpectedError(SvnErrorCode.SVN_ERR_REPOS_DISABLED_FEATURE);

        client.SetRevisionProperty(repositoryRoot, 
            revision, 
            SvnPropertyNames.SvnLog, 
            newMessage, 
            sa);

        if (sa.LastException != null &&
            sa.LastException.SvnErrorCode == 
                SvnErrorCode.SVN_ERR_REPOS_DISABLED_FEATURE)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                sa.LastException.Message, 
                "", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, SharpSvn (as well as SVN clients generally) provides mainly read-only access, and will not allow you to edit the log message on the repository. However, if you have admin access and need to edit a log message you can possibly [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion).

Comment: It is certainly possible, see my answer in a bit