# change an commited svn revision with sharpsvn

Tags: vb.net, svn, commit, subversive, sharpsvn

I have made an program that works can read out TortoiseSVN commits and shows it into listbox and a textbox.
Now I have to do this, when you press publish button then for each selected commit the logmessage needs to add [PUBLISH].

How do I update an commit and send it back to the database, in a VB script using Subversion and sharpSVN

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16292387/5555

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292387/sharpsvn-logmessage-edit-sharpsvn) in which someone asked about the possibility of changing commit details directly on the repository server through SharpSvn.

Basically, the answer is you can't (sorry), though if you have admin access on the repo,  you can [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion).