# Adding TeamCity Changes using the REST API

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

We are moving our issues to YouTrack using the REST API, which is working perfectly for description, state, attachments, type etc. However, we are losing revisions related to this issue, which we have referenced using the TeamCity build numbers.

Is it possible to add TeamCity Changes to issues using the REST API? We saw the call made by YouTrack when attaching Changes manually - we were however not able to fake this call... Is there an official way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that this is unfortunately not possible at the moment - only [Jetbrains knows why](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/YouTrack-1638)...

It seems they are able to import everything except references to their own product.

I'm however willing to accept every answer providing a useful workaround!

EDIT: We decided to modify the SVN log as a workaround ([more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion)). Since TeamCity stores commit messages in a DB,this needs an update as well. YouTrack was then able to link all builds to the correct issues ...

Answer (score 1):

You can add build numbers into appropriate Custom Field bundle ( http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Build+Bundles )
and set it in issue during import (with command, for ex.)

Comment: Yes we already considered that but we are looking for a real Integration in particular since both Products are from Jetbrains and I can't believe they forgot to add this Feature to the REST API.