# tortoisesvn edit log message not displaying

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-propset

I've read all the articles about how you can edit log messages using TortoiseSVN. I've been able to do this just fine.

However, I wanted to see if the changes I made on the server could be seen locally, and the changes I make locally can be seen on the server. This appeared to be working when I was making the changes on the server and view them locally. However, the moment I made a change to the edit log message locally, it appears that the changes are no longer visible between the two.

However, when I go to the Edit Log message, I'm able to see the message.. but it does not display in the log. anyone else had this issue?

This is what I get when I go to edit log locally. note that I've added from server on the server and it is showing up on the edit log locally but not on the show log screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIdoR.jpg

Am I missing some sort of a refresh? I've tried closing out of SVN and reopening but that did not help.

UPDATE:
looks like I've answered my own question:
see [section *Changing the Log Message and Author* of the *Revision Log Dialog* help page](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-4)

> Since TortoiseSVN keeps a cache of all the log information, edits made for author and log messages will only show up on your local installation. Other users using TortoiseSVN will still see the cached (old) authors and log messages until they refresh the log cache.

So just right-click within the repository and go to *TortoiseSVN > Settings > Log Caching* and disable/enable log caching OR under *Cached repositories*, select the one you want and update.

Comment: I had a comparable issue that was caused by a caching bug: Meanwhile (*`TortoiseSVN 1.9.5, Build 27581 - 64 Bit , 2016/11/26 09:18:58`*) the updated log message is shown as expected, but after editing a log message yesterday, I saw today the old message. The first thing I checked was the Repository itself (using ViewVC), but here was the updated log message (so no server crash, phew). Strange... Well, updating the cache helped. Thanks for your report (and update) :)

Answer (score 9):

Apparently you answered your own question, but you did it in details. Kudos.

Indeed, the correct solution to the problem is to update the local cache at the users through TortoiseSVN → Settings → Log Caching → Cached Repositories and click "Update".

Comment: In my case, just updating the cache did not help. I had to delete it (it gets recreated automatically).