# How to Associate Subversion Commit to a New JIRA Ticket

Tags: svn, jira, commit, fisheye

There are times that a commit is submitted when a JIRA ticket does not exist or the developer forgets to include the JIRA ticket number in the Subversion comment.

In such cases, is there a way to associate a commit to, say, a newly created JIRA ticket at the later time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the commit message as explained in this post:
[How to edit log message already committed in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion)

I suppose you use Fisheye to integrate JIRA and svn. To make the commit also correctly appear in JIRA, you probably have to reindex the "Subversion Non-Version Properties (revprops)" of the repository in Fisheye. This is explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/re-indexing-your-repository-298976884.html).

Comment: Thanks, however, I was aware that one can edit the SVN log message and have JIRA re-parse it, however, first, JIRA needs to be patched with a script, apparently, and second, it requires an admin right. In both cases, my user is not an admin nor the actual admin is willing to patch JIRA. Finally, this is a functionality that should really not needing this much workaround to mitigate. I take it that there is no other resolution to this problem other than what you mentioned!

Comment: You're right that it's not easy. However, you shouldn't have to patch JIRA with a script. This functionality is provided by the "developer tools integration". The supported versions of JIRA/Fisheye/... are listed here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/integrating-with-development-tools-776636216.html#Integratingwithdevelopmenttools-matrix. Probably updating the commit message and reindexing the Fisheye repo can be scripted and made available for normal users, but because this does not happen that frequently, people typically don't bother with that.

Comment: It looks like setting up the hook and refreshing Fisheye index did the job (all on admin side though).