# SVN: Change log message only by author or admin

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn, cmd, hook

I have a problem with my pre-revprop-change. I want to allow changes to the log message, but only for the author himself OR a set admin.
The code I've edited is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18005347/16739479

I've edited this part, but it doesn't work as it should:

```
set admin = muellerp
set AUTHOR=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('svnlook author -r %REV% %REPOS%') do @set AUTHOR=%%a
if /I not '%AUTHOR%'=='%user%' if /I not '%user%'=='%admin%' goto ERROR_WRONGUSER
```

If I just write

```
if /I not '%AUTHOR%'=='%user%'goto ERROR_WRONGUSER
```

everything works perfectly fine, but then the admin can't make changes.
I also have tried just to write

```
if /I not '%user%'=='%admin%' goto ERROR_WRONGUSER
```

but then it doesn't work as it should, it prints out the message within ERROR_WRONGUSER. I've also tried

```
if /I not '%user%'=="muellerp" goto ERROR_WRONGUSER
```

not even this is working, also I've checked the output of %user% is exactly the same as the name, so actually it shouldn't jump to the ERROR_WRONGUSER.

Can somebody help me, I'm pretty confused.

Comment: You should use double-quotes on both sides of the comparison since single-quotes (apostrophes) do not have a special meaning at all…

Comment: And don't mix different quotes, `if /I not '%user%'=="muellerp" goto ERROR_WRONGUSER` can't never be true, because the quotes itself will be compared, too

Comment: Moreover, quote the repository path in the `svnlook` command line in order to protect potential special characters…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set admin = muellerp` is not the correct syntax.

It should be `set "admin=muellerp"`, else you create a variable with the name `admin<space>` and the content `<space>muellerp`

A list of admins can be used by a small improvement, like:

```
set "admin_list=,mueller,schmidt,schulte,schmidtmeier,"    
if "!admin_list!" == "!admin_list:,%user%,=,###,!" echo Not an admin
```

The IF-condition is true, if both sides are equal.
But if the user exists in the list the right part will be different.

Example:
`user=schmidt` then `!admin_list:,schmidt,=,###,!` results to `,mueller,###,schulte,schmidtmeier,`

Then the complete code looks like

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "admin_list=,muellera,zernacka,"
set "AUTHOR="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('svnlook author -r %REV% %REPOS%') do set "AUTHOR=%%a"
if /I not "!AUTHOR!" == "!user!" goto :user_accepted
if not "!admin_list!" == "!admin_list:,%user%,=,###,!" goto :user_accepted

echo "!user!" is not accepted
exit /b 1

:user_accepted
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Do you know a possibility how I can create a list of admins?

Comment: I would include surrounding commas into the sub-string substitution in the list of admins in order to avoid false positives (e. g., administrators `ed` and `fred`, where the latter name contains the former one); of course the list must be augmented by a leading and a trailing comma then…

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks, very good point! I modified the code

Comment: So I've tried it with this code: `set check=true
set "admin_list=,muellera,zernacka,"    
if "!admin_list!" == "!admin_list:,%user%,=###!" set check=false
if /I not "%AUTHOR%"=="%user%" if /I "%check%"=="false" goto ERROR_WRONGUSER` but it never jumps into the ERROR_WRONGUSER, even if my name is muellerp and not muellera as declared in the admin list ?!

Comment: I got this error: Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255) with output: '"set AUTHOR=muellerp"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: @phil9 Sorry, was a typo. Fixed now `"set AUTHOR=%%a"` vs `set "AUTHOR=%%a"`

Comment: You missed a " in the sixth line after AUTHOR! but now everything is working. Thank you very much ! :) I also had to adjust the logic to `if /I not "!AUTHOR!"=="!user!" if "!admin_list!" == "!admin_list:,%user%,=,###,!" goto ERROR_WRONGUSER` so that my requirements are met.