# SVN is not recognizing the changed files

Tags: svn

I had made changes in a folder called "branch", and now that its working I want to move all the src folder to the folder "trunk". But by copying src from local branch, pasting on local trunk and commiting the SVN commits nothing. Its like nothing had changed. Any idea how to commit this?

Related question:
[How can I force subversion to commit an unchanged file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206183/how-can-i-force-subversion-to-commit-an-unchanged-file)
(Would work for me, but I know nothing about properties, exactly which one could I change and with which value to not crash something?)

Comment: @Tom Brito: You can create any arbitrary property, so you're not restricted to the properties that are already in place. The only restriction is that subversion reserves properties starting with "svn:" for their own use. Other than that, and avoiding any properties specifically used in your project, you're free to create whatever you like. Take a look at "svn help propset" for some more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do that because youre going to override the svn metadata which will cause all kinds of problems.

If branch was actually a branch and a working copy then you need to read up on `svn merge` to get the edits back to `trunk`.

If it was a folder outside of a working copy then the easiest way is to `rsync` it back in and use `--exclude=.svn` which wont sync the .svn metadata.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, try copying all the files, but not any .svn folders.

As an aside, I may be missing something, but this doesn't sound right.  Normally, you commit your changes to the repository on a branch, then merge that branch into the trunk.  What you've described sounds like you're cheating a bit.  I find it helpful to think in terms of repository files and not local files.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe (making changes in a checked out branch, then trying to commit them on the trunk by copying them on file system level) you are trying to circumvent SVN, working against it, rather than working *with* it.

I suggest you start by reading the most important chapters [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) to familiarize yourself with how SVN is supposed to be used. This shouldn'#t take longer than a few hours and will likely pay off within days. When you have to work with SVN, working *with* it, rather than *against* it, will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.