# automatic daily tagging of the SVN repository

Tags: svn, tags, cron, tagging

I want to automatically tag the daily SVN repository at 6:00 pm so that the daily code snapshot can be maintained and I could at anytime in the future go back to any earlier code repository snapshot. We we do this with a script that runs through a daily  cron job ?

Comment: you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206183/how-can-i-force-subversion-to-commit-an-unchanged-file. you can already revert to a certain day at 1800 without having to force a commit at that time.

Comment: You've been a member for a year and have never accepted a question?  Shame on you.

Answer (score 3):

The Subversion repository contains a single unique Revision number which is for the whole repository which is implicit a Tag. So the simplest solution is to use this revision number instead extra tagging step.

Comment: Plus, SubVersion supports using dates as revision numbers. Bottomline: the extra tagging is a waste of time and resources.

Comment: Subverison does not use dates as revision numbers. It has an integer as revision number. The date is a revision property to the revision.

Comment: I haven't said that it is using dates as revision numbers but that it also *supports* using dates instead. See [Revision Specifiers in the SubVersion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html).