# SVN Add file every commit or merge, even if not changed

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, svn-merge, svn-propset, svn-config

Can I force SVN to commit/merge a specific file every time even if the file doesn't change?

I know you can ignore a file but what about something like 'Always Commit' option?

I'm using the revision number SVN Tags `$Revision$` in one file, I parse the file and use that revision number as a variable as I wanted to eliminate doing this manually before a merge. I wanted just to have the Revision number update as it does what it is committed. Only problem is I still need to manually do this and I would like to automate this, thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate (and answered) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206183/how-can-i-force-subversion-to-commit-an-unchanged-file

Comment: Ah, not quite a duplicate then. You should look into a pre commit hook (http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the file from a file, cause SVN only updates this revision if the file has really been changed. The best thing is to use svnversion on command line to get the information you need.
Furthermore eliminating it before the merge is not needed, cause SVN will handle that for you...cause the expansion of the Keyword into the revision number is done by the SVN client which means in other words the file is stored in the repository with not expanded keywords. 
I don't know in which programming language you are working but usually this should be done by a build system.

Answer (score 0):

Using SVN not in its way is wrong, means updating the version though the file is not actully updated.

Solution i feel is taht , if the file isunchandes for somany release , tag it separatly.

when you do automatic build use both the tags, thus u dont need to update the version of that file.