# Force SVN (tortoise) to check-in a file to update Revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revision, checkin

I have a file that contains the revision placeholder in the form:

```
$Rev: 123456 $
```

The file is checked-in only if it changes, so, if I want to commit it just to update the revision number, I am forced to add a fake change (example: adding a space, a new line, something like that) in order to been able to see it in the change-list and commit it, obtaining the result I am looking for.
Even if I modify the revision flag, writing for example:

```
$Rev: 0 $
```

SVN is "smart" enough to ignore this change...

Is there a (clean) way to simply tell SVN (tortoise) that the file must be checked in without using these "tricks"?

NOTE: This is needed because the revision number in used in the build. This allows us to clearly identify the version of the build when it is run.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206183/how-can-i-force-subversion-to-commit-an-unchanged-file)

Answer (score 0):

1. As suggested in linked topic, you can always change some property of file before commit. But if you want to play with content, [part of answer](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#detectmodification) from TortoiseSVN FAQ will be useful for you (starting from "Subversion determines whether a file has changed with the following approach...")
2. From other side, I'll seriously suggest you to re-think about current workflow and use The Right Things for The Right Job - don't rely on keyword of file (file-revision) in order to obtain global repository-wide revison

For "getting repository revision" task you have at least 3 different tools, 2 from which are part of **any** Subversion, 1 is part of TortoiseSVN:

- Svnversion. `svnversion <Path-to-WC>` output global revision number of linked to WC repository, clean numbers without decorations, ready for inclusion into anything

`>svnversion`

`37`

(inside WC I skipped path, "." assumed). Output must be translated into smth. like "Latest revision in repo is 37, Working Copy is clean /no uncommited changes, no spare-dirs, state of WC can be reproduced lately/"

`>svnversion`

`37M`

*Same Working Copy, but changes was performed and still not committed*

- Info. `svn info <TARGET>` output more verbose information about target, but can be used with **repository URL** also, not only Working Copy

`>svn info`

`...`

`Revision: 37`

`...`

`Last Changed Date: 2013-01-09 11:45:39 +0600 (Ср, 09 янв 2013)`

Only `Revision` field (and, probably, `Last Changed Date`) values have interest in this case, but this data must be extracted from output

- [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#subwcrev) and sample of usage for TortoiseSVN code inside FAQ-topic

Answer (score 0):

another approach would be to, simple add a placeholder(empty text file)in the same location and commit this new file along with unchanged file. Later the text file can be deleted.