# How do I commit a symlink whose origin file changed and is outside the repository?

Tags: svn, commit, symlink

I backup a directory with svn.  Some of these files are symlinks whose origins are not in the repository.  I had no problem adding the symlinks to the repository when it was created.  However, when the origins change, the symlinks are not collected in the next svn commit.

My present solution is to manually adjust a properly as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206183/1484957) question.  Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: SVN has a special property that do this job. It is called svn:special and is automatically set by svn client, you don't have to set it. Why this didn't works for you?

Comment: I was not aware of svn:special.  I've checked and my svn client (linux command line subversion) automatically set the svn:special property on the symlinks when added them to the repo.  However, they are still not pulled in on subsequent commits automatically.